# I cannot edit the record within the text file. Language: JAVA IDE: NETBEANS

Tags: java, netbeans, error-handling, runtime-error

I have problem of editing my record within the text file. The logic in the code is that you enter a 13 digit number (which is unique/variable used cnic), then it reads the text file.

If the line doesn't not contain that number it copies that line onto another text file created (Voters Database2.txt). If it does, it asks for the new information and user enters it and then copies that information to new text file.

When "cnic" is entered it searches using the line.contains(...) method to search the record to be edited. With BufferedWriter Created and if condition set to boolean, if false it should copy that line onto the next text file and if true ask for. The problem is when the program asks for the user to enter cnic, and when entered, it starts going in infinite loop in if brace.

Here is the code:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
    String cnic,ncnic,vn,list,nm,age,adrs;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Voters Database.txt"))) {
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Voters Database2.txt",true));
            System.out.println("Enter Voter CNIC to edit");
            cnic=in.nextLine();
            String line=br.readLine();
            while (line!=null){
                boolean x=line.contains(cnic);
                if (x==true){
                    System.out.println("Enter new CNIC");
                    ncnic=in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new Voter Number");
                    vn=in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new list no");
                    list=in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new Voter's Name");
                    nm=in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new Age");
                    age=in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new Address");
                    adrs=in.nextLine();
                    line="CNIC: "+ncnic+" Vote Number: "+vn+" List No: "+list+" Name: "+nm+" Age: "+age+" Address: "+adrs;
                    bw.write(line);
                    bw.close();
                }
                else{
                    bw.write(line);
                }
                br.readLine();
            }
        }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("IO Exception Error");
    }
```

Comment: @UmaKanth its not try function, its [try with resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) introduced in JDK7.

Answer (score 1):

It will go in infinite loop since it won't find `line` as null, here's the reason:

You set line as below which would mean line won't be null

```
String line=br.readLine();
while (line!= null) ..
```

Now within the while loop itself you never reset it to null and hence it leads to infinite loop.